# Hierarchical Data Binding to a flat WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

How can you 'two-way bind' a hierarchical data structure to a flat wpf datagrid?

The application interface model is **iTunes** - I am looking for the datagrid to appear flat (not a master/detail grid).  The user sees rows containing an Artist, Album, and Song; but the data is stored hierarchically where an Artist contains a list of Albums which contains a list of Songs.

When the user renames an Album, the hierarchy automatically finds or creates the new Album (based on Album.Name) for the given Artist, and moves the Song to the Album.

Adding a translation layer between the flat data and the hierarchical data seems like a poor solution.

**Update 1** 
After reading through the answers, it appears achieving what I've described above can't be done without a lot of work behind the scenes.  It seems I should reconsider representing my data in this fashion.

Comment: @soandos I'm trying to figure out a smart way to do it, I'm not sure if there is a known solution - I came across the ITypedList interface and don't know if this would be appropriate.  It seems like I'm trying to design a binding to a binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flattening of the structure can be done by using a LINQ projection. [See the one-to-many projection in this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqOneToManyProjection.aspx).

All you have to take care of is that you re-query when the collection changes.

I do not see a way of making it any easier and a translation layer will always be needed whether it be a LINQ query or a special binding or a converter unless you find a grid that will do it for you.

Comment: Would you consider including a reference to the parent object in the Hierarchy, and trying to find a way to bind up the structure, i.e. Album.ParentArtist?

Comment: Yes, I would consider that (I might call it Album.Artists but that's just me because I expect a many-to-many relationship)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the translation layer either but that seems to be the easiest solution.

Aside from that, you could write your own custom template. So for example if you have the data structured like: Album>Song and you want it to be displayed like in this picture: http://files.jerahmeelcosinas.net/stackoverflow/itunes.jpg

it would something along this lines:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}">
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Image Source="{Binding AlbumImage}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SongName}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SongLength}" Header="Length" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

You could switch the ItemsControl Template during runtime to switch between views (for a flat song list or a list sorted by album).